# Facebook Auth Dialog not requesting email permission for user

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth

I added the email permission to the "User & Friend Permissions" of my Auth Dialog.

Unfortunately, it is not requesting this permission when my users authorize my application.

The Auth Dialog is just requesting the Basic Info.

What is interesting, when I Preview the Auth Dialog it shows it requesting the email permission.

Is anyone else having this problem?

Thanks,

Comment: @zerkms:   I use the FB.login function of the Javascript SDK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to pass `email` in a scope like it's done in the second example here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/

```
 FB.login(function(response) {
   // handle the response
 }, {scope: 'email'});
```

Comment: thanks for that!  I don't understand why I have to set up my App to request email and then also request the email when I make the FB.login method call, but this obviously is what is required as it works for me.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you are confusing a login you trigger yourself (like by calling FB.login), and a login that is triggered by Authenticated Referrals – what you set in your app settings for the latter does not affect any login calls you make yourself, it only affects those situations where Facebook triggers the connect to your app automatically. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/authentication/#referrals